# h5py installment error: cannot find -lhdf5

Tags: python, linux, gcc, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to install the [keras](https://github.com/fchollet/keras) package for python on a openSUSE server where I don't have root access. According to the instructions, I should install numpy, scipy, pyyaml, Theano, HDF5 and h5py. The server already has numpy and spicy, I installed pyyaml and Theano using "pip install XXX --user".

I downloaded HDF5 source and installed it by running the ./configure, and it was installed successfully, under folder "/home/myname/software/hdf5". Now the last step is to install **h5py**, where I was stuck in and can't find solutions online.

I tried:

> HDF5_DIR=~/software/hdf5/ pip install h5py --user

And getting the following error:

> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
>   cannot find -lhdf5
>   /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
>   cannot find -lhdf5_hl
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Then I tried:

> CFLAGS="-I/usr/lib/openmpi/include/ -I/home/myname/software/hdf5/include" LDFLAGS="-L/home/myname/software/hdf5/lib" pip install h5py --user

But getting the same error. I downloaded the source and tried:

> HDF5_DIR=~/software/hdf5/ python setup.py install --user

But still getting the same error. It seems that the installer is not trying to look for things in my customized hdf5 folder. Could you help me on this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Might be a shot in the dark, how about using `${HOME}` instead of `~`?